# Find Regex word

Tags: php, regex

What is regular expression to find tag like this:

> Here is text and there is tag **@username can be spaces here (#A345D78)** and this is end!

I need to find by:

- Tag starts with "@"
- Then somewhere will be "(#"
- And always after 8 symbols from # will be ")"

So, important match parts are: @ (#********)

Thanks

Language is PHP

Valid:

> @Martin's Van Der Buren (#6575GT67)

Not valid:

> @Martin's Van Der Buren #6575GT67)
>
> @Martin's Van Der Buren (6575GT67)
>
> @Martin's Van Der Buren (#6575GT67

Comment: Regex are language specific. What's your environment language? And yes, where's your problematic code?

Comment: Give an actual sample of something that should match and something that shouldn't.

Comment: E.g. Is "@This is a tag or so #12123434)" a valid tag?

Comment: Is `username` needed, or you only need the 8 characters after `#`?

Comment: Please show ACTUAL data and ACTUAL output expected. Include all possible situations that need to be accounted for in the data.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? regex101.com is good place to try regexs out.

Comment: I have tried many expressions, but nothing. I didn't remember all of them.

Comment: Do you remember any of them? It'd be good to know if it is your PHP usage or regex.

Comment: @.*?\(#\d{8}\) This works, only in 8 digits place can be letter too: 12AB34DC

Comment: Use `.` in place of `\d`. A `.` is any single character excluding new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
@.*?\(#.{8}\)
```

This will match an @ followed by any number of characters then the pattern (#12345678)

Comment: I don't think after the `#` is necessarily numbers, `8 symbols from #`. (although in example it is)

Comment: @chris85 OP gave 8 digits, let's wait for clarification. Anyway, it's easy to switch  from \d to whatever he needs

Comment: @Racoon Then use `\w` or `[A-Z0-9]` instead of `\d`.  This is pretty basic.  You still haven't really said what it is you're having trouble with, specifically.

Comment: By the way, if the user name cannot contain `(` characters, it would be more efficient to use a negative character class (e.g. `[^(]*`) than a lazy expression (e.g. `.*?`).

Comment: Username can contains anything

Answer (score -1):

I'll bite!  See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iI2kS5/1) for a working example.

```
@.* \(#.{8}\)
```

Comment: Jup tnx. Thomas Ayoub was first :)

Comment: That's not a requirement

Comment: Ok, I give up, why the neg? It's basically the same as the accepted answer, except for a space.  lol